# Prime Ideals of a ring

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The definition of a prime ideal is:

An ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ is said to be a prime ideal if $I \neq R$ and $f.g \in I \implies f \in I$ or $g \in I$

My understanding of this is that $f.g \in I$ means **atleast** $f$ or $g$ has to be in $I$ and we can't have a case where two non-elements of $I$ combine to give us an element of $I$. But surely we can also have **both** $f,g \in I$ or is it only one element that has to be in $I$ (Sorry if the question seems confusing, but this is the best way I could put it)

Comment: Yes, both is allowed by the definition.

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between "**or**" and "**either...or**".  You have "$f$ or $g$ (or possibly both)" compared to "either $f$ or $g$ (but not both)".

Comment: Either also need not imply exclusive or. In general in mathematics if we use or the possibility of both happening is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) page. In particular you might be interested in the truth table
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline f&g&f\lor g \\\hline T&T&T \\\hline T&F&T\\\hline F&T&T \\\hline F&F&F\\\hline \end{array}.$$

What this table says to you is that if the statement "$f$" and the statement "$g$" are true **then** the statment "$f$ **or** $g$" is true, because both $f$ and $g$ are true.

Similarly if the statement "$f$" is true and the statement "$g$" is not true, **then** the statement "$f$ or $g$" is true, because $f$ is true.

I let you do the other cases.

In your specific case the statement "$f$ or $g$ must lie in $I$" is the third column of the table. I.e.: it is true if $1)$ both $f\in I$ and $g\in I$ is true, or $2)$ if $ f\in I$ but $g\notin I$, or $3)$ if $f \notin I$ but $g\in I$.

There is also a joke, which might help you understand the concept:

"The wife of a logic has barely had a child. She asks her husband: "is he male or female?" He answers: "Yes"."

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You very much. The more I do algebra, the more I get interested in logic, might be time for me to start reading up on logic myself